# Как настроить Socks5 proxy на Selenium для chrome в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, socks5

никак не получается настроить socks5 прокси (и http кстати тоже) на Selenium. Перепробовал кучу способ. И через опции

```
self.options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://'+proxy)
```

и через

```
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "socksProxy": proxy,
        "ftpProxy": proxy,
        "sslProxy": proxy,
        "noProxy": None,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
        "autodetect": False
    }
```

И тд. Видимо где то я делаю ошибку, **пожалуйста опишите полностью рабочий пример настройки socks5 прокси на Selenium для Python и Chrome webdriver, с привидением форматов строки прокси(ибо может я тут туплю...)**. Пишу от безысходности уже...Заранее большое спасибо!

PS два типа проблем возникали при попытках установить прокси разными способами:

1. Просто оставался старый айпишник, не ставился прокси.
2. Пропадал доступ в интернет через webdriver. 
   Просто почему то очень много способов в интернете находил, но результата пока что не добился

**Update:**
Попробовал способом предложенным ниже. IP не удается изменить

```
proxy = 'name:pass@ip:port'
service_args = ['--proxy='+proxy, '--proxy-type=socks5']
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chrome_webdriver, 
                          service_args=service_args)
driver.get('https://2ip.ru/')
```

**Update:**
Получилось использовать прокси socks5 без аутентификации с помощью следующего кода:

```
 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
```

При добавлении

```
 options.add_argument('--proxy-auth=' + proxy_auth)
```

Пропадает подключение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Хром не поддерживает прокси с аутентификацией по логину и паролю** Я в этом не уверен, но очень много информации изучив я пришел к этому. Единственное решение, которое для меня подходит - это использовать прокси без аутентификации по логину и паролю (можно использовать аутентификацию по IP)

```
 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 proxy = '12.12.421.125:1949'   
 options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте через `service_args`:

```
service_args = ['--proxy=127.0.0.1:9050', '--proxy-type=socks5', '--proxy-auth=admin:admin']
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chrome_webdriver, service_args=service_args)
```

**Update:**

```
proxies = [
    {
        'addr': '123.123.123.123:1234',
        'auth': 'admin:admin'
    },
    {
        'addr': '200.2.2.2:7868',
        'auth': 'foo:bar'
    },
]

for proxy in proxies:
    service_args = ['--proxy=' + proxy['addr'], '--proxy-type=socks5', '--proxy-auth=' + proxy['auth']]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chrome_webdriver, 
                              service_args=service_args)
    driver.get('https://2ip.ru/')
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный вариант. Соединение не пропадает, но IP адрес не изменяется. Я пробовал передавать данные о socks5 прокси в таком формате - '--proxy=login:pass@ip:port'. Может быть здесь что то не так?

Comment: @DmitrySharko что значит IP не меняется? Если вы хотите поменять IP прокси, вам нужно перезапустить `webdriver` и в `service_args` указать другой прокси сервер. Вы публичными прокси пользуетесь?

Comment: Нет, не публичными. У меня свои прокси. Проверенные в других условиях - работают =) Добавил точное описание варианта, предложенного вами. Если я не правильно реализовал что то то пожалуйста скажите.

Comment: @DmitrySharko я обновил ответ. Попробуйте перезапускать драйвер с новыми настройками прокси. Должно помочь.

Comment: Исправил в ответе .close() на .quit() так как close() закрывает только текущее окно, а их может быть несколько, а quit() закрывает браузер, сколько бы окон не было.

Comment: Спасибо большое за предложенные варианты, я попробовал точно так, но ИП все равно не меняется. Не верится что у всех это работает, а у меня почему то нет. Не понимаю в чем проблема...

Comment: @DmitrySharko под какой ОС работаешь?

Comment: @RezvanovMaxim OC Windows 10.  Начитался очень много уже в интернете по этому вопросу. Люди пишут что проблема может возникать из-за того, что прокси требуют аутентификации.

Comment: @DmitrySharko я тебе написал пример с аутентификацией в апдейте. `--proxy-auth=admin:admin`

Comment: @RezvanovMaxim да, спасибо большое еще раз, я выполнил все в точности, и понимаю суть попытки. Я пробовал уже даже делать в точности как в ролике на ютубе хах. Через агрументы для Firefox браузера, но на видео у человека работает, а у меня даже обычное http любое прокси без аутентификации как будто не встает...Ищу проблему. хочу попробовать запустить код на другой машине - отпишусь

Comment: Сделал Update способа с ChromeOptions() и прокси без аутентификации